# What is the Java import for OpenCV 4.8.0 estimatePoseCharucoBoard()?

Tags: java, opencv, aruco, opencv-solvepnp

The current OpenCV Java documentation indicates that `estimatePoseCharucoBoard()` is still a viable Java method in `org.opencv.aruco.Aruco`. I don't have that class and I can't find the method in any other classes that I have. I see some nearby, related methods have been moved or deprecated or replaced. I can't find any information about `estimatePoseCharucoBoard()` except it should be available. I see SO posts about looping through all the markers to duplicate the functionality of the missing `estimatePoseSingleMarkers​()` or use solvePnP. Has `estimatePoseCharucoBoard()` met with a similar but undocumented fate?

Comment: boards have been turned into their own objects. browse the C++ docs. nobody really maintains the java bindings or the docs. java is a strange and complex ecosystem that doesn't attract anyone who knows OpenCV itself (C++)